# Remove word accidentally added to dictionary in Kate

Tags: kate, spell-checking

I misclicked when correcting a spelling error when using Kate and added the misspelled word to my dictionary, how do I go about removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimentally, I entered a wrong word on purpose, and then used `find`+`grep` to search it the various `~/.*` directories. This didn't find anything. So I closed the file in Kate, reopened a new one, re-entered the same word, and it was marked wrong again. I conclude that "Add to dictionary" is only temporary for the current file.

Incidentally, *Settings>Configure Kate>Editor Component>Editing>Spellcheck* has a list of "ignored words", so I guess that this is what you use to enter words permanently.

Comment: Damn. I just added a lot of words! At least I don't need to worry about my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [Kate documentation](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/katepart/config-dialog.html) did not specify where it would be, I'd suggest you launch [Kfind](https://kde.org/applications/utilities/org.kde.kfind) to do a contents search for the misspelled word. First, look in **~/.config** and if not found there, search again in **~/**  .